# Flow of current inside source

Tags: voltage-source

Does current flow in/inside an ideal AC voltage source/generator like it flows in an ideal electrochemical battery? How does the process happen?

Answer (score 2):

It does not really make sense to talk about what happens 'inside' an ideal (theoretical) source. An ideal source is simply defined by the voltage and current equations that describe it. It is just a mathematical construct that forms a kind of boundary conditions on our system.